# Strange python dictionary keys

Tags: python

I encounter a strange dictionary. Let's call it `cp_dict`. When I type:

```
 cp_dict['ZnS-Zn']
```

it returns:

```
 {Element Zn: -1.159460605, Element S: -4.384479766249999}
```

The child key looks like a string but without quotation marks. How I can access the child keys (for example: `Element Zn`) and modify the values? I tried `cp_dict['Zn3P2-Zn'][Element Zn]`, and the error is

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

The `cp_dict['Zn3P2-Zn']['Element Zn']` leads to:

```
KeyError: 'Element Zn'
```

I checked `type(cp_dict['ZnS-Zn'])` . It returns `<class 'dict'>`.

Comment: `type(cp_dict['ZnS-Zn'])` is not the question, you want to know the type of the keys in that dict. Have you tried passing one of those to `type()`?

Comment: The keys of the inner dict are of some custom class, that we cannot identify from the information posted.  You can try `type(next(iter(cp_dict['ZnS-Zn'].keys())))` - but surely the documentation for the module that's giving you this object would tell you how to use it?

Comment: @jasonharper I checked the documents how this ```cp_dict ``` was generated, and solved the problem. That is, I can access the child key by ```cp_dict['ZnS-Zn'][Element('Zn')]```, where ```Element``` is an object imported from ```pymatgen.core.periodic_table ```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite easy to make a custom class which represents itself in that way ("looking like a string but without quotation marks"). The result returned by a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method is what gets used when representing instances inside collections such as dicts and lists:

```
>>> class Element:
...     def __init__(self, symbol):
...         self.symbol = symbol
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return f"Element {self.symbol}"
... 
>>> d = {Element("Zn"): -1.159460605, Element("S"): -4.384479766249999}
>>> d
{Element Zn: -1.159460605, Element S: -4.384479766249999}
```

So, my guess is the keys of the dict are the strange items, not the dict itself. Check the type of a key, and look up it's `__repr__` method. You can get the type of the first key with:

```
k = next(iter(cp_dict["ZnS-Zn"]))
Element = type(k)
```

To index the dict you will need an instance which compares equal with one of those keys. Again, look up `type(k).__eq__` for that. If the `__eq__` method is not customized, then you will need to use the identical key to index this dict, since the equality method will just be the default identity-based implementation which is inherited from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object).